# Efficient way of parsing XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have to parse an XML file with following structure:

```
<root>
    <object_1>
        <pro1> abc </pro1>
        <pro2> pqr </pro2>
        <pro3> xyz </pro3>

        <children>
            <object_a>
                <pro1> abc </pro1>
                <pro2> pqr </pro2>
                <pro3> xyz </pro3>

                <children>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                </children>
            </object_a>
        </children>     
    </object_1>
    <object_2> 
    .
    . 
    .
    </object_n>
</root>
```

Aim is to parse this multilevel nesting. A few classes are defined in Java.

```
Class Object_1
Class Object_2
.
.
.
Class Object_N
```

with their respective properties.

The following code is working for me, but then this is not the best way of doing things.

```
File file = new File(fileName);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

if(doc ==null) return;

Node node = doc.getFirstChild();

NodeList lst = node.getChildNodes();
Node children = null ; 

int len = lst.getLength();
for(int index=0;index<len;index++)
{
    Node child = lst.item(index);
    String name = child.getNodeName();
    if(name=="Name")
        name = child.getNodeValue();
    else if(name=="Comment")
        comment = child.getNodeValue());
    else if(name=="children")
        children = child;
    }

    if(children==null) return; 

    lst = children.getChildNodes();
    len = lst.getLength();
    Class<?> obj=null;
    AbsModel model = null;
    for(int index=0;index<len;index++)
    {
        Node childNode = lst.item(index);
        String modelName = childNode.getNodeName();
        try {
            obj = Class.forName(modelName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(obj!=null)
            model = (AbsModel) obj.newInstance();
        else
            model = new GenericModel();

        model.restoreDefaultPropFromXML(childNode);
        addChild(model);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of parsing this XML.

Comment: You can also use some XML deserialization (XStream, ...)

Comment: I agree with the gentleman - but it kinda depends on your requirement of efficiency: XPath is probably not going to perform as much as SAX or your current solution. But it is probably less prone to errors and less work to maintain.

Comment: Also **DON'T** use == for `String`, use `equals()`

Comment: I'm surprised the code is working at all, given that you're using `==` to compare strings...

Comment: Does your xml have `<object_1>` to `<object_n>` elements, or a list of `<object>` and `<pro>` elements?

Comment: There are whole books about the technologies available for parsing XML from Java, and their relative strengths and weaknesses. You might get snippets of advice here, but if you want to make a well informed decision, you need to do some serious reading.

Comment: @Jon .. I was surprised as well.. But the code work. I checked it in the debug mode.

Comment: @chai: Something must be interning the strings, basically... but it's still not a good idea to rely on it.

Comment: The Strings are equal most likely equals because the are created on the same call stack (and thread) so Java reuses the String reference. Lisp does the same thing with Cons cells but far more aggressively. An easy way to make this not work is to load the XML into objects in one thread and consume it in another :)

Answer (score 9):

Consider using [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/), which is part of Java since version 6. You should be able to parse (“unmarshall”) your XML file into your own classes with almost no code, just adding a few annotations expliciting the mapping between your object structure and your XML structure.

Comment: JAXB is a good choice if the structure is stable, the schema is reasonably simple and not extensible, and there is no mixed content.

Answer (score 0):

**StAX** and or **JAXB** is almost always the way to go.

If the XML is really dynamic (like attributes specify the property name) ie `<prop name="property" value="" />` then you will need to use **StAX** only or live with what **JAXB** will map it to (a POJO with name and value properties) and post process.

Personally I find combining StAX and JAXB the best. I parse to the elements I want and then use JAXB to turn the element into a POJO.

**See Also**:

- My own utility library that will turn an [XML Stream into an iterator of objects](https://gist.github.com/3752190).
- [Parsing very large XML files and marshalling to Java Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746950/parsing-very-large-xml-files-and-marshalling-to-java-objects)
- http://tedone.typepad.com/blog/2011/06/unmarshalling-benchmark-in-java-jaxb-vs-stax-vs-woodstox.html

Answer (score 0):

While JAXB may be the best choice I'd also like to mention [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/)  which provides a JQuery-like API and makes working with XML documents really pleasant.